# Trying to rewrite a code to include the modulus operator

Tags: c++, extract, modulus, digits

The problem is as follows:

Input is the "t" number of data sets, followed by t 11-digit numbers. There's a cipher included in the code as an array. The code is supposed to multiply the subsequent digits from the input number by the corresponding digits from the cipher, thus creating a sum of 11 multiplications. After that the code checks whether the sum is divisible by 10. If so, it returns "correct", if not - "incorrect".

I've written a code which works as intended, but I'd like to simplify this code, specifically to include the modulus operator instead of fmod to extract the digits from the 11-digit input numbers. I've tried using modulus, but it can only be utilized for an int.

I found a code for a simple reversed order digit extractor (using the while loop and %10), but I'm having some trouble implementing it in my code... Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   long long int number;
   int cipher [11] = {1,3,7,9,1,3,7,9,1,3,1};
   int t, digit, sum;

   cin >> t;
   for (int i=0; i<t; i++)
   {
        sum = 0;
        cin >> number;

        for (int j=10; j>=0; j--)
        {
            digit = fmod(number/(pow(10,(10-j))),10);
            sum = sum + digit*cipher[j];
        }
        if (sum%10==0)
            cout << "Correct" << endl;
        else
            cout << "Incorrect" << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

An example of a correct number is 44051401458. We're assuming all the input numbers are always 11 digits.

Comment: `digit = fmod(number/(pow(10,(10-j))),10);` -- A program such as this does not need floating point calculations or functions such as `fmod` and `pow`.  Those functions have the potential for round-off error.  This program can be done using only integers and integer calculations.

Comment: Try changing `number` in the loop to be the value needed in the next iteration - that can eliminate need to raise a value to value to a power - and work out how to eliminate use of floating point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are referring to. You can just keep dividing number by 10, which will shift the decimal point. It will not turn into a float since you defined number as an int (long long int), so any decimal point just gets erased and you can use modulus freely.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   long long int number;
   int cipher [11] = {1,3,7,9,1,3,7,9,1,3,1};
   int t, digit, sum;

   cin >> t;
   for (int i=0; i<t; i++)
   {
        sum = 0;
        cin >> number;
        for (int j=10; j>=0; j--)
        {
            digit = number%10;
            number = number/10;
            sum = sum + digit*cipher[j];
        }
        if (sum%10==0)
            cout << "Correct" << endl;
        else
            cout << "Incorrect" << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Huh, weird, I'm 99% sure I tried something almost identical to your solution, but I kept having problems with the loop... Anyway, works like a charm and looks much more simple, thank you! :)